# How can I get the SonarQube issues in NetBeans12.4?

Tags: plugins, netbeans, sonarqube

I'm developing JAVA in NetBeans 12.4 and as code analyzer I'm using SonarQube, which actually works well.
The problem is the netbans-radar plugin is not available anymore.

So, here is my question:

How can I get the SonarQube issues on NetBeans 12.4?

Any idea will be great!

Answer (score 1):

To see SonarQube/SonarCloud issues in IDE you need to install [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/). SonarLint provides official support for:

- [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij)
- [Eclipse](https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse)
- [Visual Studio](https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio)
- [VS Code](https://www.sonarlint.org/vscode)

I found unofficial plugin: [SonarLint for NetBeans](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=21). I have no idea if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments.
I just install/configure it but is working only locally. I do not see the possibility to work with a SonarQube server where the project is analyzed and then from NetBeans you get the issues to work on.

And the other plugin nb-sonarlint does not really work properly to get issues as well